# Converting a date string in C#

Tags: c#, date, datetime, string-formatting

I have a date string with the format "dd.MM.yyyy" (eg. "01.02.2004") and want to convert it to "yyyy-MM-dd" with **String.Format(...)** or **DateTime.ParseExact(...)** or whatelse.
Actually I only get exceptions. So the usage of the following code doesn't work:

```
String dateString = "01.02.2004";
datestring = String.Format("{yyyy-MM-dd}", dateString);
```

What is wrong with that? Is there an alternative with  `DateTime.ParseExact(..)`?

Comment: Did you read the string.format() documentation? At all?

Comment: Note that String.Format needs an ordinal: `String.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", dateValue);` (note the `0:` signaling the first value). Plus that value needs to be a DateTime for that format to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a Datetime object first.

try something like:

```
DateTime t = DateTime.parse("01.02.2004");
String result = t.ToString("{yyyy-MM-dd}", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to parse it into a `DateTime`, then call `ToString()` with a different format:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "dd.MM.yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to convert it to a `DateTime` first with an appropriate `CultureInfo`:

```
String dateString = "01.02.2004";
var deCulture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("de-DE");
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(dateString, deCulture);
dateString = dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/ae5wGc)

Answer (score 1):

```
String dateString = "01.02.2004";
dateString = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "dd.MM.yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                     .ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

What's wrong with your attempt is:

- When using a format string, the items need to be listed in a format like `{0:yyyy-MM-dd}`. The `0:` is necessary.
- When you're using string.Format(), the variable is a `string`, so the format string `yyyy-MM-dd` has no meaning there.

Answer (score 1):

You're parsing a string as argument to String.Format? What do you expect out of it?

You should do something like this:

```
try
{
 var date = DateTme.ParseExact("yyyy.MM.dd", dateString, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
 var result = date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
}
catch(Exception e) { /* ... */}
```

Comment: Why not use TryParseExact?